# How do I get the whole data that is being sent

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code, I want to get the whole data that is being sent by the client . but the problem is that it's printing the character one by one.

like this

```
receive data ?
receive data ?
receive data _
receive data Z
receive data
receive data O
receive data ?
receive data }
receive data .
receive data ?
receive data (
receive data ?
receive data ?
receive data G
receive data ?
receive data "
receive data ?
receive data ?
receive data ?
receive data ?
receive data C
receive data ?
receive data C
receive data ?
receive data ?
receive data a

var net  = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket){
      socket.on('data',function(data){
           console.log("receive data",data.toString());
      });
});

server.listen(3333,'127.0.0.1', function () {
    console.log("server is up!");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Not tested but try this:

```
    var net  = require('net');
    var response="";
    var server = net.createServer(function(socket){
          socket.on('data',function(data){
               response+=data.toString();
          });
          socket.on('end',function(data){
               console.log("received data", response );
          });
    });

server.listen(3333,'127.0.0.1', function () {
    console.log("server is up!");
});
```

Comment: can we set size to receive ?

Comment: I get problem, the clients needs to disconnect first to the socket in order to get the the data but they simultaneously send data to socket.what if i have 10 clients together sending data to socket but they are not disconnected yet.so I think I missed some of there data